# Docker on AWS - what is a difference between Elastic Beanstalk and ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I want to migrate from Heroku to Amazon AWS and I would like to deploy my app in Docker image. So the app consists of:

- Web server (node.js -> docker image)
- Worker (node.js -> docker image)
- Postgres database (Amazon RDS)
- Redis instance (Amazon ElatiCache?)

With my app I (Web+Worker):

- I have to be able to scale both web and worker instances manually or auto.
- update with new image with zero-downtime
- see realtime/history metrics
- see realtime/history logs

And now when studying Amazon docs I found "Elastic Beanstalk" and "Amazon EC2 Container Services (ECS)". I was wondering which one should I use to manage my application (docker images)? What is a difference between them?

Answer (score 7):

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) uses the [Amazon EC2 Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) under the hood for its [Multicontainer Docker Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html), and the difference is addressed by the resp. FAQ [How is Amazon ECS different from AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/faqs/)

> **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** [...]
>   **keeps the provisioning of building blocks** (e.g., EC2, RDS, Elastic
>   Load Balancing, Auto Scaling, CloudWatch), **deployment of applications,
>   and health monitoring abstracted from the user so they can just focus
>   on writing code**. You simply specify which container images are to be
>   deployed, the CPU and memory requirements, the port mappings, and the
>   container links. **Elastic Beanstalk will [...] handle all the
>   details such as provisioning an Amazon ECS cluster, balancing load,
>   auto-scaling, monitoring**, and placing your containers across your
>   cluster.
>
> [...] **You can work
>   with Amazon ECS directly if you want more fine-grained control for
>   custom application architectures.** *[emphasis mine]*

Furthermore, only Elastic Beanstalk supports Heroku's push deployment model (see the [deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) command of the [EB Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)), so for your scenario I would definitely recommend to look into Elastic Beanstalk's [Multicontainer Docker Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html), rather than using [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) directly.

Comment: It would be great, If you list down the fine-grained control in ECS that we do not get in EB.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar It's mentioned: "provisioning an Amazon ECS cluster, balancing load, auto-scaling, monitoring, and placing your containers across your cluster"